# Nested IF with FIND

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a list of transactions in column A that I want to categorize.

I want to search A1 for, say, "Shoprite" and if found return "Groceries", otherwise search for "Shell" and return "Gas", otherwise search for "Netflix" and return "Entertainment"

I tried (among other things):

```
=IF(FIND("Shoprite",A1), "Groceries", IF(FIND("Shell",A1),"Gas", IF(FIND("Netflix", A1),"Entertainment")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- try like this:

  ```
  =IF(A1="Shoprite", "Groceries",
   IF(A1="Shell", "Gas",
   IF(A1="Netflix", "Entertainment", )))
  ```
- if **A1** doesn't say exactly **`Shoprite`**, but rather **`Shoprite on 7th`**, then use this:

  ```
  =IF(A7=IFERROR(FILTER(A7, (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Shoprite", A7)))), ), "Groceries",
   IF(A7=IFERROR(FILTER(A7, (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Shell",    A7)))), ), "Gas",
   IF(A7=IFERROR(FILTER(A7, (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Netflix",  A7)))), ), "Entertainment", )))
  ```

Comment: Going with the second one since it might not say exactly, but it only works for the first search term. So Shoprite will return "groceries, but if A1 contains Shell, I get nothing. A mock sheet so you can see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AvhTD_bCnkEBi_uK1-_-htyRLjWH1nFdlFj1yGfhx_c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: formula fixed, answer updated, try now

Comment: Yassss! That fixed it. Thanks!